# How to calculate $\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{\sin^2x-\sin^5x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

For $\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{\sin^2x-\sin^5x}dx$, I've tried to several different ways, like
$$\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{\sin^2x-\sin^5x}dx=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin^2x-\sin^5x}dx,$$
or let $u=\sqrt{1-\sin^3x}$, but neither of them works.
I'm doubting if there is a solution.

Comment: There must be a solution. And the answer is about 1.12982.

Comment: Was it an exam question?

Comment: If the $5$ would have been a $4$ or a $6$ one could easily compute the integral.

Comment: It's not an exam, but someone ask me for help. I sadly found I can't solve it analytically.

Answer (score 3):

$$I=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin^2 x-\sin^5 x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}2t\,\sqrt{\frac{1+t+t^2}{1+t}}\,dt $$
and by using the substitution $t=\frac{1}{2}\left(-1+u+\sqrt{u^2+2u-3}\right)$ we get:

$$ I = \frac{9\sqrt{6}-8}{20}+\color{blue}{\int_{1}^{3/2}\frac{(u+2)\sqrt{u(u-1)}}{\sqrt{u+3}}\,du} $$
where the blue integral is an elliptic integral, equal to:
$$ 2\int_{2}^{3/\sqrt{2}}(u^2-1)\sqrt{(u^2-4)(u^2-3)}\,du.$$
Numerically, $I\approx 1.1298158$.

Comment: The explicit value of the integral is $$\frac{1}{5} \left(3 \sqrt{6}-2+12 i ~F\left(i~ \text{csch}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)|\frac{1}{4}\right)-12 i ~E\left(i~ \text{csch}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)|\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)=$$ $$=1.1298158061973205974...$$

Comment: @YuriyS: thank you for the addendum!

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio, don't mention it. In the end I just used Mathematica on the blue integral